# Protocol Extension Initializer forcing to call self.init

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I was just reading the Apple Swift 4 document regarding the Protocol Initializer Requirements and providing a default implementation in the protocol extension.

```
import UIKit
protocol Protocol {
    init()
}
extension Protocol {
    init() {
        print("SDf")
        self.init() // Line 1
                    // Compiler error occured if this is omitted 
                    //"'self.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer"
    }
}

struct Structure: Protocol {
    init(string: String) {

    }
}

Structure()      // Line 2
```

Now as you can see, the execution will go into a loop, as by default the structure doesn't have an implementation for `init()`, so the protocol provided init will be called and it will call itself again, and so it goes into an infinite loop.

Now, knowing this, if I remove Line 1, the compiler gives the error.

Q. Why is it forcing me to use `self.init()` on Line 1, and how can I get out of this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
protocol P {
  init()
}

extension P {
  init() {

  } // error: 'self.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer
}

struct S : P {
  var str: String
}

let s = S()
print(s.str)
```

Suppose it compiled – we'd be able to create an `S` value without providing a value for the `str` property. That's why the compiler is complaining that your protocol extension implementation of `init()` isn't calling `self.init`. It needs you to chain to *some other* initialiser requirement – one that you don't provide a default implementation for (otherwise you could get into a recursive loop, as you found out), and therefore one that the adopting type needs to implement such that it can fully initialise itself.

For example, this is legal:

```
protocol P {
  init()
  init(str: String)
}

extension P {
  init() {
    self.init(str: "some default")
  }
}

struct S : P {
  var str: String
}

let s = S()
print(s.str) // some default
```

because now we're chaining to the `init(str:)` requirement, which `S` *must* implement (in this case it's satisfied by the [implicit memberwise initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID213)).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Cleared my doubt.

Comment: @Hamish, while you're right (I upvoted your answer) I find your explanation a bit confusing. One might still ask why you can't just give `str` a default value (e.g. `var str = "some default"`) in the struct without calling `self.init()` from the extension. I think the simple answer is that a protocol extension can't anticipate what *other* properties a conforming type might have, and therefore it can't guarantee complete initialization on its own—it needs to refer to the actual type definition for that (much like a convenience initializer has to call a designated initializer for classes.)

Comment: This could definitely have been made clearer in the [Swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html#ID153). The only real clues are the code examples and one little side note that reads: 'If you provide a new initializer with an extension, you are still responsible for making sure that each instance is fully initialized once the initializer completes.'