# swift protcol extension chaining initialization of class

Tags: swift

How to initialize if I change the following struct to class :-

```
protocol P {
    init()
    init(str: String)
}

extension P {
    init() {
        self.init(str: "some default")
    }
}

struct S : P {
    var str: String
}

let s = S()
print(s.str) // prints - some default
```

I tried adding default memberwise initializer (after changing to class) :-

```
class S : P {
    var str: String
    init() {
        self.init(str: String)
    }
}
```

It shows  error: -
error: type 'S' does not conform to protocol 'P' class S : P. There are other errors too. How to get initialization done if I change struct to class ?

Comment: You need to add something like `required init(str: String) {self.str = str}`

Comment: I may have over-edited your question. The more I look at the second piece of code, the less sense it makes. Can you make sure it's your actual code?

Comment: @Sweeper - your answer is working

Comment: @Rob Napier - Its alright. You are right, its not my actual code.  Its from one of the other stackoverflow questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270261 - answered by Hamish. I changed the struct to class and was getting errors.

Comment: Can you update to be your actual code; the answer I'm sure is really straightforward, but we need to know exactly what mistake you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes don't get a default initializer. You just need to write the ones that aren't provided by a default implementation:

```
class S : P {
    var str: String
    required init(str: String) { self.str = str }
}
```

`required` is needed here for non-`final` classes, because all subclasses must also implement this method. It is not required for `final` classes:

```
final class S : P {
    var str: String
    init(str: String) { self.str = str }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to specify `required` for non-final classes.

It might help if you learn the concepts, the Swift documentation would help.

## Code:

```
class S : P {

    required init() {}
    
    required init(str: String) {}
}
```

Comment: I believe the required keyword isn't the solution, it's that the asker's code forgot the `init(str: String)` required by the protocol. Just needed to implement that init.

Comment: Without required keyword it would throw a compilation error

Comment: @user1046037 - your answer shows error. Sweeper's answer is working.

Answer (score 0):

Class `S` needs an initializer to initialize `str`! Structs generate this initializer themselves, but you have to write it for classes!

```
required init(str: String) {
    self.str = str
}
```